# Image has contents that are not what they are reported to be

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, paperclip, paperclip-validation

I am getting the following error while using the paperclip GEM.I have tried uploading JPG/PNG and neither works. It seems like I am getting validation error..any help would be awesome thanks!

```
Image has contents that are not what they are reported to be

class Listing < ActiveRecord::Base
     has_attached_file :image, :styles => { :medium => "200x", :thumb => "100x100>" }, :default_url => "404.jpg"
validates_attachment_content_type :image, :content_type => /\Aimage\/.*\Z/
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your are using in windows 7 development mode. U need to manually install file.exe and set the path. Please follow the content in the link 
[installing file.exe manually](https://github.com/thoughtbot/paperclip).

After installing

Environment

1. Open `config/environments/development.rb`
2. Add the following line: `Paperclip.options[:command_path] = 'C:\Program Files (x86)\GnuWin32\bin'`
3. Restart your Rails server

Answer (score 0):

This worked for Windows 8:

1.Download [file.exe](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/file.htm)

2.Test if is well installed by running your cmd and put the following instructions
**convert logo: logo.miff** then run **imdisplay logo.miff**

You will get custom logo image,that will pop up on your windows screen.
From here now you can start configuring everything on rails app

*Open config/environments/development.rb*

Add the following line: Paperclip.options[:command_path] = 'C:\tools\GnuWin32\bin'
If your rails server is currently running,brake the server and then run again rails s.After that you should be ready to go.Upload image on your app.